# How to enable Workspace compilation override for a workspace in DataForm?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dataform

Currently, we are using Workspace compilation override set at the Repository level to separate datasets for Prod and Dev by appending a PostFix to the Schema, which we use for the Dev environment. However, we've found out that Workspace compilation override is associated only with the Repository and not with individual Workspaces, making it unsuitable for segregating workspaces during multi-person development.

Is the only way to separate multiple individual development environments to use an override in dataform.json? Managing dataform.json in this manner would be special, which I want to avoid.

How is everyone handling this? Please share your best practices.